# Expected norm of a product of Gaussian matrices

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

Suppose $C_n$ is a product of $n$ $d\times d$ matrices with IID entries coming from standard normal. The following [appears](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/mathoverflow-second-gaussian-moment-simulation.nb) to be true. Is there an elementary proof?

$$E[\|C_n\|_F^2]=d^{n+1}$$

This follows from [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4818479/998) on math.SE on the moment method, but unclear how to adapt it to this, since the moment method requires fixing $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This follows from the fact that $\mathbb{E}[A^\dagger A]=d I$ (with $A^\dagger$ the conjugate transpose of $A$ and $I$ the $d\times d$ identity matrix). Hence
$$\mathbb{E}[\|C_n\|_F^2]=\operatorname{tr}\mathbb{E}[A_1A_2\cdots A_nA_n^\dagger\cdots A_2^\dagger A_1^\dagger]$$
$$=\operatorname{tr}\mathbb{E}[A_2\cdots A_nA_n^\dagger\cdots A_2^\dagger]\mathbb{E}[ A_1^\dagger A_1]$$
$$=d\operatorname{tr}\mathbb{E}[A_2\cdots A_nA_n^\dagger\cdots A_2^\dagger]$$
$$=d\operatorname{tr}\mathbb{E}[A_3\cdots A_nA_n^\dagger\cdots A_3^\dagger]\mathbb{E}[ A_2^\dagger A_2]$$
$$=d^2\operatorname{tr}\mathbb{E}[A_3\cdots A_nA_n^\dagger\cdots A_3^\dagger]$$
$$=d^{n-1}\operatorname{tr}\mathbb{E}[A_n^\dagger A]=d^n\operatorname{tr} I=d^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Ah, that's a lot simpler than the moment method, thanks!